Would it be possible to use Diamagnetic force working along with gravity to make a sort of two-way stream?
I was wondering if it would be possible for someone to generate some sort of two-way stream by positioning a strong NdFeB magnet below an upward pointing tube containing something like a Bismuth or Pyrolytic Carbon liquid solution. The magnet would push up on the Diamagnetic solution causing it to flow upward until it reached the top of the tube. From there it would turn and flow into a downward pointing tube where the force acting upon the fluid would no longer be magnetism and diamagnetism but rather gravity, causing the solution to flow downward where it would turn and again be forced upward by the magnet. Would something like this likely be possible and be able to power a turbine? If it is, where would the energy be coming from to cause the rotation? Would it be energy drawn from the electromagnetic and gravitational fields extending through space, or perhaps from something else? I would be very grateful to know the opinion of someone is more knowledgeable than I am. Thank you.

No, perpetual mobiles are impossible. The fluid would also be pushed upwards in the downward pointing tube.
